# Optimize Spark Shuffle Multi Join

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

Need help in optimizing the below multi join scenario between multiple (6) Dataframes.
Is there any way to optimize the shuffle exchange between the DF's as the join keys are the same across the Join DF's.

```
final_df = DF1.join(DF2,['ID1','ID2','ID3'],'leftouter')
final_df = final_df.join(DF3,['ID1','ID2','ID3'],'leftouter')
final_df = final_df.join(DF4,['ID1','ID2','ID3'],'leftouter')
final_df = final_df.join(DF5,['ID1','ID2','ID3'],'leftouter')
final_df = final_df.join(DF6,['ID1','ID2','ID3'],'leftouter')
```

any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What's the row count you are dealing with in DF1, DF2, DF3, DF4, DF5 and DF6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see 2 possibles optimizations in your case,

1. If some of your dataframes are relatively small size, you can
   broadcast these small dataframes, let's suppose DF4 and DF6 are
   small, you can do something like this:

   ```
   from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast
   final_df = DF1.join(DF2,['ID1','ID2','ID3'],'leftouter')
   final_df = final_df.join(DF3,['ID1','ID2','ID3'],'leftouter')
   final_df = final_df.join(broadcast(DF4),['ID1','ID2','ID3'],'leftouter')
   final_df = final_df.join(DF5,['ID1','ID2','ID3'],'leftouter')
   final_df = final_df.join(broadcast(DF6),['ID1','ID2','ID3'],'leftouter')
   ```

   This can be tricky since small dataframes can be relatively
   different depending on the context and the size of the cluster, so
   if you fell not sure, you can broadcast each dataframe alone from
   the others and see if it's okay
2. It's always good to repartition the dataframes on the joining
   columns, before joining, a good place to do that is when you are
   reading your dataframes, ex:

   DF1 = spark.read.xxx.repartition(80, "ID1", "ID2", "ID3")

   Replace 80 by the number of cores across all different executors
   multiplied by 2, 3 or 4, so if you have 20 core in your cluster
   try to repartition by 40, 60 or 80, and keep the one that gives the
   best results.

After all these you may have particular problems like data skew, very large dataframes ..., that you need to handle separately.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the solution, Lachiheb. So here we cannot Optimize the shuffle(s) meaning as we are doing the join based on the same keys, we still have to shuffle each result set again ?  looking to avoid any shuffles as we are doing the joins based on the same keys. is it possible ?Thanks.

Comment: The fact that you are joining on same or different keys is irrelevant, spark don't care, what you can do is to have the same keys on the same executors, so the shuffle will be minimized, this can be done only with repartition which will lead unfortunately to a shuffle